# Fsharp interactive fu

Tags: reflection, f#, f#-interactive

I have a variable in fsharp interactive

```
val toto : obj = [["NKY INDEX"]]
```

(I got that value from a call to a regular dotnet library, whose prototype tells me it returns an **obj** )

I would like to access the value inside of it, but I don't know exactly the type.
So I try to reflect on it :

```
>toto.GetType();;
val it : Type =
  System.Object[,]
    {Assembly = mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;
     AssemblyQualifiedName = "System.Object[,], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089";
     Attributes = AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public, Sealed, Serializable;
     BaseType = System.Array;
     ContainsGenericParameters = false;
     CustomAttributes = seq [[System.SerializableAttribute()]];
     DeclaredConstructors = [|Void .ctor(Int32, Int32);
                              Void .ctor(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)|];
     DeclaredEvents = [||];
     DeclaredFields = [||];
     DeclaredMembers = [|Void Set(Int32, Int32, System.Object);
                         System.Object& Address(Int32, Int32);
                         System.Object Get(Int32, Int32);
                         Void .ctor(Int32, Int32);
                         Void .ctor(Int32, Int32, Int32, Int32)|];
     DeclaredMethods = [|Void Set(Int32, Int32, System.Object);
                         System.Object& Address(Int32, Int32);
                         System.Object Get(Int32, Int32)|];
     DeclaredNestedTypes = seq [];
     DeclaredProperties = [||];
```

It has a Get method, however, when I try to retrieve the element, I get an error.

```
>toto.Get(0,0);;

  toto.Get(0,0);;
  -----^^^

  error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Get' is not defined
```

What is the correct way to retrieve the inside element ?

PS : casting it beforehand yields the same

```
>(toto :?> System.Object[,]).Get(0,0);;

(toto :?> System.Object[,]).Get(0,0);;
----------------------------^^^

error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Get' is not defined
```

same for .[0, 0]

```
> toto.[0, 0];;

  toto.[0, 0];;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^

error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Item' is not defined
```

Comment: The expression `toto : obj = [[""]]` shouldn`t even compile.

Comment: this is unfortunate consequence that list of lists and multidimensional arrays are printed in the similar fashion in FSI

Comment: @JaredPar I failed to mention, because I thought the displayed information was sufficient, I get this value from a dotnet function call. whose return type, in all its glory, is object....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine

```
let arr = toto :?> obj[,]  // downcast to actual type
let item = arr.[0,0]
```

is what you want.

Comment: Something seems amiss though. The original type should be a `string list list` correct?  Going by the `val toto : obj = [[""]]` sample. Which also doesn't seem like it should compile without an explicit cast.

Comment: try to enter code from my answer to FSI. original object is boxed string[,]

Comment: still a typo in there; second toto should be arr. or in one go: let item = (toto :?> obj[,]).[0,0]

Comment: @JaredPar - Just because FSI prints it like that doesn't mean its type is that.  The ToString display of an array can look like a list; try: `Array2D.init 1 1 (fun _ _ -> box "");;` and see `val it : obj [,] = [[""]]`

Comment: it works indeed. although I am not sure I thoroughly understand the logic : if I do toto.GetType() I get System.Object[,] . If I look through FsEye, toto and arr are exactly the same. So at which point is FSI preventing the indexer access ? (knowing that the return type in the prototype function is obj, so toto must be an obj to some which would explain)

Comment: ok I get it, the gettype method is a member of the System.Object. This might return an underlying type, obj[,] in this case, but my variable toto is for all means of type  System.Object, therefore I can not call any method but the  System.Object's one before casting it down.

Answer (score 2):

```
let toto = box (Array2D.init 1 1 (fun _ _ -> "NKY INDEX"))
(toto :?> string[,]).[0,0]
```

Comment: He has an `obj[,]`, yes?  As though the string literal inside the lambda is also boxed?